# Multibit desktop wallet not updating Bitstamp exchange rate

Tags: multibit

For some reason Multibit is telling me bitcoin is at $460 on Bitstamp when it's closer to $490. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The exchange rate updates relatively slowly (every hour or I think for BitStamp) so as to avoid all the copies of MultiBit hitting the BitStamp servers too much.

It is obviously bitcoin that is being sent in a transaction so in any sale or purchase it is the bitcoin figure that you want to agree to rather than the "USD (Bitstamp)" or "GBP (OpenExchangeRates)" figure.